# Grails 4.0.0 database migrations setup - cannot find class CommonsLoggingLiquibaseLogger using IntelliJ

Tags: gradle, grails, spring-security, grails-orm, liquibase

My [Grails Spring Security Core](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/latest/#tutorials) app fails at runtime after I add the following to build.gradle:

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:3.0.4'
```

This line is directly from the [Grails database migration plugin](https://guides.grails.org/grails-database-migration/guide/index.html) tutorial for setting up migrations, but my project blows up after I add it. I receive the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/liquibase/CommonsLoggingLiquibaseLogger
```

Has anyone encountered this? Can you suggest a fix please?
Using Grails 4.0.0, IntelliJ, Windows 10.

The full error output:

```
2019-09-13 10:40:40.658 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/liquibase/CommonsLoggingLiquibaseLogger
    at org.grails.plugins.databasemigration.DatabaseMigrationGrailsPlugin.configureLiquibase(DatabaseMigrationGrailsPlugin.groovy:97)
    at org.grails.plugins.databasemigration.DatabaseMigrationGrailsPlugin.doWithSpring(DatabaseMigrationGrailsPlugin.groovy:50)
    at org.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin.doWithRuntimeConfiguration(DefaultGrailsPlugin.java:539)
    at org.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager.doRuntimeConfiguration(AbstractGrailsPluginManager.java:166)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:171)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:97)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:458)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:445)
    at marinedebristracker.Application.main(Application.groovy:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.liquibase.CommonsLoggingLiquibaseLogger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I needed to add to build.gradle instead, cleared the liquibase error right up:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:3.1.0.RC1'
}
```

found here: https://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/database-migration